# Changing value by pointer within function

Tags: pascal

I want to use a simple function (sqr for a number)

```
function stepenadr(adresss:pointer):real;
begin
stepenadr:=adresss^*adresss^;
end;
```

by using an adress of real variable

```
 adress:=@x1;
```

like this:

```
writeln(x1,'^',2,'=',stepenadr(adress));
```

however it gives me errors like this operation cannot be done, or that it cannot dename pointers. Adress is an a

```
adress :pointer;
```

Does not work like this also:

```
function stepenadr(adresss:pointer):real;
begin
stepenadr:=adresss*adresss;
end;
```

Comment: Um... Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Part of homework in University, and the last time I`ve done something in pascal was really long time ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, got it to work by doing this:

```
function stepenadr(adress:^real):real;
begin
stepenadr:=adress^*adress^;
end;

adress:=@x1;
writeln(x1,'^',2,'=',stepenadr(adress));
```

Answer (score 3):

A untyped pointer points to an anonymous empty record which can be seen by running the following program:

```
var p  :pointer;
begin
  writeln (sizeof(p^)); // will print 0
end.
```

The untyped pointer has as advantage that it accept any information, but info(type) to what it points to is lost during the assignment of a typed pointer to an untyped function. As you found out.

Solution is to keep it typed, or in rare cases typecast:

```
type preal=^real;

function stepenadr(adresss:pointer):real;
begin
  stepenadr:=preal(adresss)^*preal(adresss)^;
end;
```

which explains to the compiler how to interpret the pointer (as preal), and then the type the pointer points to is defined again.

This can go catastrophically wrong though if adresss originally didn't point to real, since then the compiler might interpret random memory as real.